# Convert canvas to image in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make canvas and user will draw some picture in that which I want to save as Image. I am using Python 3.3.2. It doesn't support PIL or Image module. Can someone guide me on this..?

Thanks.

Comment: [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) is a fork of PIL that also works on newer versions of Python, including Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit too late to answer this question. But, I'll still go ahead.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

r=Tk()
canvas = Canvas(r,height=1000,width=2000,bg="snow") 
def getter():
    x2=r.winfo_rootx()+canvas.winfo_x()
    y2=r.winfo_rooty()+canvas.winfo_y()
    x1=x2+canvas.winfo_width()
    y1=y2+canvas.winfo_height()
    print("save")
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x2,y2,x1,y1)).save("./test.jpg")


b1=Button(r,text="Save",command=lambda:getter())
b1.grid()
```

Let me know if this doesn't work. Hope it helps..